# Multiple gesture responders at the same time

Tags: react-native

I need some buttons that can be pressed at the same time, but currently if you press one, it 'claims' responsiveness and the others can't be pressed anymore. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Got it. You have to use `ReactNativeEventEmitter` to directly listen to touch events and bypass the Gesture Responder stuff entirely. Below is a decorator class that calls `onTouchStart`, `onTouchEnd` and `onTouchMove` in the wrapped class whenever those touch events are received.

```
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react-native';
import ReactNativeEventEmitter from 'ReactNativeEventEmitter';
import NodeHandle from 'NodeHandle';

export const multitouchable = BaseComponent => {
    return class extends Component {

        constructor(props, context) {
            super(props, context);

            this.comp = null;
            this.compId = null;
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            if(this.comp && this.compId){
                this.comp.onTouchStart && ReactNativeEventEmitter.putListener(this.compId, 'onTouchStart', e => this.comp.onTouchStart(e));
                this.comp.onTouchEnd && ReactNativeEventEmitter.putListener(this.compId, 'onTouchEnd', e => this.comp.onTouchEnd(e));
                this.comp.onTouchMove && ReactNativeEventEmitter.putListener(this.compId, 'onTouchMove', e => this.comp.onTouchMove(e));
            }
        }

        componentWillUnmount() { 
            if(this.comp && this.compId){
                this.comp.onTouchStart && ReactNativeEventEmitter.deleteListener(this.compId, 'onTouchStart');
                this.comp.onTouchEnd && ReactNativeEventEmitter.deleteListener(this.compId, 'onTouchEnd');
                this.comp.onTouchMove && ReactNativeEventEmitter.deleteListener(this.compId, 'onTouchMove');
            }
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <BaseComponent {...this.props} {...this.state}
                    ref={c => {
                        this.comp = c;
                        const handle = React.findNodeHandle(c);
                        if(handle)
                            this.compId = NodeHandle.getRootNodeID(handle);
                    }}
                />
            );
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This definitely helped me, but is it working for you for latest version of react native? (0.27) Looks like NodeHandle doesn't exist anymore, it was replaced by findNodeHandle, but that returns integer instead of object that is expected as a first parameter for ReactNativeEventEmitter.putListener method. However, you can create object with key _rootNodeID and pass that to putListener. Then it worked for me.