# Unable to resolve module ReactNativeEventEmitter

Tags: react-native

After upgrading React Native from 0.29 to 0.30, I get this error message. I multiple times deleted node_modules, installed them back again, cleared watchman cache and npm start --reset-cache.

I tried it also on new project with react-native init someProject. The same error. Was this module renamed or deleted? I haven't found any info about it in release notes or in commits.

Thanks for help!

Comment: how did you required it?

Comment: Using ES6 import statement: import ReactNativeEventEmitter from 'ReactNativeEventEmitter';

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's no longer needed. onTouchStart, onTouchEnd and onTouchMove are props of Views now.
[Look here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/a2fb703bbb988038323c55b29b40e8f5ff52966d/Examples/UIExplorer/js/PointerEventsExample.js)

Comment: Where the heck is this in the documents. Thanks. You deserve more upvotes. So many use cases

Comment: RN documentation seems ridiculously outdated. Thanks for this. The source code is the documentation I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, what really happened to this component.

But, at least, currently on RN 0.30 you can require ReactNativeEventEmitter as follows:

```
var ReactNativeEventEmitter=require(127);
```

The following line ...

```
console.log(ReactNativeEventEmitter)
```

...will print then this in the console (in Debug-Mode):

[image]

(I've figured it out while searching the react-native libraries in "node-modules" in the following file: "./node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/androidTest/assets/AndroidTestBundle.js:13879", and it is also working under iOS [the screenshot above originates from iOS]).

Comment: Doesn't work for me, when I require it using number 127, console.log outputs: http://imgur.com/qPQGL1N

Comment: hm... i wrote exactly the same code that ReactNative uses itself in their classes

Comment: this is really weird, I just inited new project using "react-native init testProject" and added your line "var ReactNativeEventEmitter = require(127);" and I when I console log it, I get the same thing: imgur.com/qPQGL1N

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to import using below snippet?

```
import { DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but apparently API of it is different. I'm using ReactNativeEventEmitter for multitouch gestures on multiple views at the same time: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125728/multiple-gesture-responders-at-the-same-time). I had a look at DeviceEventEmitter module definition and I see that order of arguments is different, but it's not clear to me what should I pass as a context argument if I want to listen to touch event of particular view.

Comment: hmm.. sorry I don't  think I can answer this further.