# Respond to and track multiple touches (multiple responders) in React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, touch

I'm looking to track multiple touches on multiple elements at the same time with React Native (I have multiple "knob" type buttons, and a user should be interact with more than one at a time). However, it seems that with the native gesture and/or PanResponder, only one element can be responder at a time.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

I found this old answer: [Multiple gesture responders at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125728/multiple-gesture-responders-at-the-same-time) but the internals of React Native have changed so much since that I can't identify how to do the same thing.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38748677/2315280) please

Comment: Perfect! I'll give that a go. Thanks very much. Feel free to post as an answer rather than comment and I'll mark as resolved.